# How to set flag in bash function for setting aliases?

Tags: bash, terminal, browserify

This is the command i want to execute

```
watchify files/[filename].js -t hbsfy -o out/[filename].js
```

i tried this

```
javascriptCompile() {
  foo="src/js/files/$1.js -t hbsfy -o src/js/out/$1.js"
    watchify "$foo"
}

alias jc=javascriptCompile
jc main
```

I get this error

You MUST specify an outfile with -o.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to be an array:

```
javascriptCompile () {
  foo=(src/js/files/"$1".js -t hbsfy -o src/js/out/"$1".js)
  watchify "${foo[@]}"
}
alias jc=javascriptCompile
jc main
```